# Objective-C Noob: How to define + call a method in main?

Tags: objective-c

I wrote a method that works inside of an object, but now I want to extract it so that it's just a function. This is my broken command line tool program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

+ (NSMutableString *)reverseString:(NSString *)originalString {
    NSMutableString *reversedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = originalString.length; i > 0; i--) {
        [reversedString appendFormat:@"%c", [originalString characterAtIndex:i-1]];
    }

    return reversedString;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *originalString = @"original string";
        NSMutableString *newString = [reverseString:originalString];

        NSLog(@"Reversed string: %@", newString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, how would I call the reverseString method from `main()`? I don't think I'm defining it properly. Do I have to declare it too? I know that the contents of my method work fine, but I don't know how to define it in a way that allows main to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "method" is, by definition, part of a class. There are two types, instance methods and class methods. To invoke an instance method, you need, well, an instance of the class. To invoke a class method, you don't need an instance. You can just invoke it directly on a class.

By contrast, there are also "functions". You don't need an instance or a class to invoke a function.

So, it sounds like you want a function. Functions are something that Objective-C inherits from C. The syntax for functions is different from the syntax for methods. Here's how your code might look using a function:

```
NSMutableString* reverseString(NSString *originalString) {
    NSMutableString *reversedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = originalString.length; i > 0; i--) {
        [reversedString appendFormat:@"%c", [originalString characterAtIndex:i-1]];
    }

    return reversedString;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *originalString = @"original string";
        NSMutableString *newString = reverseString(originalString);

        NSLog(@"Reversed string: %@", newString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, your code does not "work fine". You can't iterate through a string by what it calls "characters" and treat all of them as independent. What `NSString` calls "characters" are actually UTF-16 code units. Not all Unicode characters can be expressed as single UTF-16 code units. Some need to use two code units in what's called a surrogate pair. If you split up and reverse a surrogate pair, you'll get an invalid string.

As a separate issue, Unicode has combining marks. For example, "é" can be expressed as U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT. Again, if you reorder those "characters", the accent will combine with a different character (or fail to combine at all).

The correct way to iterate through the composed character sequences of a string is to use the `-[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` method with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option.

Answer (score 1):

By "I want to extract it so that it's just a function" you're implicitly saying "I want a C-style function, not an Objective-C class method".  C-style functions are declared and called differently (blame history).

```
static NSMutableString * reverseString(NSString * originalString) {
    ...
}

...

    NSMutableString *newString = reverseString(originalString);
```